# Retrieving key/identifier of array of JSON objects before iterating through that array via NewtonSoft Linq

Tags: json, linq

Is there a method of retrieving the 'key' of an array of JSON objects before iterating through said array? I'm trying to associate the values in each array with the associated key, and I'm having trouble figuring out whether to use JArrays, JObjects, etc. while parsing it with NewtonSoft's Linq library.

```
{
    
    "DENSE_FOREST": [

        {
            "Terrain_Key": "FIELD_GRASS",
            "Name" : "Grassy Field"
        },

        {
            

        }
        
    ],

    "TEST" : [

    ]
}
```

For example, I want to be able to get the name/string "DENSE_FOREST", iterate through the associated array so I can pull data from it and associate it under "DENSE_FOREST" in a data structure I'm using, and then go onto "TEST", and so forth.

I'm trying to iterate through it as a JArray but the syntax is confusing me and the examples I've found online don't apply exactly to my issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a method of retrieving the 'key' of an array of JSON objects
> before iterating through said array?

The example `json` string you have provided is a `JObject` so you would parse it like this first:

```cs
string jsonData = @"{
            ""DENSE_FOREST"": [
                {
                    ""Terrain_Key"": ""FIELD_GRASS"",
                    ""Name"": ""Grassy Field""
                },
                {
                    ""Terrain_Key"": ""FOREST"",
                    ""Name"": ""Forest Area""
                }
            ],
            ""TEST"": []
        }";

JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
```

then proceed to search for a `JProperty` with key `DENSE_FOREST` in the `jsonObject` cast it to a `JArray` and retrieve the contents.

```cs
 // Retrieve the specific key "DENSE_FOREST"
JArray denseForestArray = (JArray)jsonObject["DENSE_FOREST"];

 // Check if the key exists and is an array
if (denseForestArray != null && denseForestArray.Type == JTokenType.Array)
{
  // Process the items in "DENSE_FOREST" array
   foreach (JObject item in denseForestArray)
   {
      string terrainKey = item.Value<string>("Terrain_Key");
      string name = item.Value<string>("Name");

       Console.WriteLine("Terrain_Key: " + terrainKey + ", Name: " + name);
     }
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("Key 'DENSE_FOREST' does not exist or is not an array.");
}
```

You can also test out the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nwr191).

**Edit**

To iterate through all items in the `JObject` you would do it like this:

```cs
foreach (var property in jsonObject)
{
    string key = property.Key;
    Console.WriteLine("Key: " + key);

    //cast JProperty value to JArray
    JArray jsonArray = (JArray)property.Value;
    foreach (JObject item in jsonArray)
    {
      string terrainKey = item.Value<string>("Terrain_Key");
      string name = item. Value<string>("Name");

      Console.WriteLine("Terrain_Key: " + terrainKey + ", Name: " + name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to iterate through it without hard-coded calls to the specific keys? I want to retrieve each key's name and then iterate through the associated array. That would be done using the JBobject's children property, correct?

Comment: @Hazeron Yes, also added how on you can do that.

Comment: Thank you kindly, I appreciate the help!